# C#: Math Round() results different values for different decimals

Tags: c#, .net, rounding

I am getting a different value when using `Math.Round` with different decimal points, can someone correct me where am I going wrong.

```
   double r = Math.Round(1.235, 2,MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
   double t = Math.Round(19.185, 2,MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

`r` results in 1.24 and whereas `t` results in 19.18, the expected result for `t` is 19.19.

Comment: Have a look at this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=netframework-4.8#rounding-and-precision)

Comment: Use decimal for better precision

Comment: Consider that the exact value of 1.235 as stored in binary floating point is 1.2350000000000000976996261670137755572795867919921875 and 19.185  is 19.184999999999998721023075631819665431976318359375

Answer (score 4):

Accroding to [`Math.Round`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=netframework-4.8#System_Math_Round_System_Double_System_Int32_System_MidpointRounding_), **Notes to Callers** section

> Because of the loss of precision that can result from representing
>   decimal values as floating-point numbers or performing arithmetic
>   operations on floating-point values, in some cases the `Round(Double, Int32, MidpointRounding)` method may not appear to round midpoint
>   values as specified by the `mode` parameter. This is illustrated in the
>   following example, where 2.135 is rounded to 2.13 instead of 2.14.

This sounds like your exact case, due the loss of precision `19.185` is rounded to `19.18` instead of `19.19`. You can display values using the `G17` [format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings?view=netframework-4.8#GFormatString) to see all significant digits of precision

```cs
Console.WriteLine(1.235.ToString("G17"));
Console.WriteLine(19.185.ToString("G17"));
```

The output will be something like that

> 1.2350000000000001
>
> 19.184999999999999

As possible workaround, you can use `decimal` values with better precision

```
var r = Math.Round(1.235m, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
var t = Math.Round(19.185m, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

The result will be expected

Comment: Finally a really good explanation of what's happening underneath. Thank you! 
I was also wondering why C# and MSSQL rounded the same number differently. Appears to be that when I set my number to float (in c#) I got the same result as in SQL, but when I had decimal, there was difference in 0,01.